# Example of flask-autoindex and lazy loading

Tags: python, flask

I currently have this in my script:

```
index = AutoIndex(app, browse_root=dir_to_index, add_url_rules=False)

@app.route('/indexed')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def autoindex(app=None, path='.'):
    return index.render_autoindex(path, template='indexed_dir.html', endpoint='.autoindex')
```

I would like to use a lazy view instead for better separation of my logic:
i.e.

```
views.py
from flask import render_template

def autoindex(app=None, path='.'):
    return index.render_autoindex(path, template='indexed_dir.html', endpoint='.autoindex')
```

Then in my script something like:

```
app.add_url_rule('/indexed', view_func=views.autoindex)
```

However, since I have two decorators, not sure about how to best go about this. Also, I believe I may have to deal with app/request context.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `route` is just another call to `add_url_rule` under the hood:

```
app.add_url_rule('/indexed', view_func=views.autoindex)
app.add_url_rule('/<path:path>', view_func=views.autoindex)
```